# is_dir fail when executed in parallel with the script creating the dir

Tags: php

EDIT : My problem came from the "intelligent" behaviour of Firefox. If you call the same page on two different tabs, it automatically start the second after the first is done. If you want parallel execution you must add a different parameter.

Was trying to create a mutex using a directory. For exemple :

```
$dir = 'test' ;
echo is_dir($dir) ;
mkdir($dir)
wait(30)
rmdir($dir)
```

In a browser, I call the script, on another tab a few seconds later I call the same script.

is_dir returns false and there isno error on mkdir on the second call
ON the disk the dir is created with the first script and remain until the second end.

If I call on command line the two script one after the other I have the
expected result is_dir is true and mk_dir failed with dir already exists error.

The web server is an apache2.

Can't explain such a behavior.

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea what your question is, but the gist makes me think that you're getting caught out by the stat cache? http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me: Why do you think you need to mimic mutexes in PHP? The request cycle is what it is, PHP is stateless, and 2 concurrent requests don't actually share state (as far as the PHP code you write is concerned). Mutexes exist to prevent race conditions and concurrent access to memory (state) shared by multiple threads. Unless you're trying to do something really weird, PHP simply doesn't need them, which is why PHP doesn't have the functionality built-in

Comment: @JonStirling: You're probably right in saying that the OP's question can be answered by explaining how PHP handles the actual IO operations internally (buffering IO and caching system calls). However, the real question I think the OP should be asking is _why_ he's trying to create directories as some sort of mutex system in PHP

Comment: @Ootegem the script is working as a cache, we call a web server to get a file and to avoid to call this site each time it cached the file. Every hour it compares the last version with the new one and change it if modified and serve the callers the local file. So the cached server is not called each time a script need the file. And today the server stop responding so at each call the script search for the the new file creating to much tcp  call due to the timeout delay. 

So i'm triyng to prevent subsequent call when one script is trying to access the file server.

Comment: @Régis: So it's a caching mechanism, not a mutex. Please don't call it a mutex, because that made me think all sorts of horrible things...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explain a bit better, and paste a better code exemple...

Meanwhile, here is a better way to handle your mkdir/rmdir

```
$mydir= 'my/dir/'

if(!is_dir($myDir)) {
    mkdir($myDir, 0755, true);
    wait(30);
    rmdir(mydir);
}
```

You might need to find out how to recursively delete dirs and files, it might help... ;)

Also, is `wait()`a PHP function you made?!
I do know `sleep()` but not `wait()`...

Comment: My bad, forgot to edit that part of the code... Just fixed it... ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use stat(), lstat(), or any of the other functions listed in the affected functions list (below), PHP caches the information those functions return in order to provide faster performance. However, in certain cases, you may want to clear the cached information. For instance, if the same file is being checked multiple times within a single script, and that file is in danger of being removed or changed during that script's operation, you may elect to clear the status cache. In these cases, you can use the clearstatcache() function to clear the information that PHP caches about a file.

This function caches information about specific filenames, so you only need to call clearstatcache() if you are performing multiple operations on the same filename and require the information about that particular file to not be cached.

Affected functions include stat(), lstat(), file_exists(), is_writable(), is_readable(), is_executable(), is_file(), is_dir(), is_link(), filectime(), fileatime(), filemtime(), fileinode(), filegroup(), fileowner(), filesize(), filetype(), and fileperms().

TLDR, add a clearstatcache(); before any checks

source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: BUSTED!.. I was looking at my local php.chm help file and realized I was basically rephrasing what I read there so I copied it.  I've since added the source. Hopefully that is sufficient to keep me out of the dog house

Comment: Just to practice what I preach: According to the [PHP licensing page](https://secure.php.net/license/), the manual is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license, which boils down to [this](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/): Redistribution is allowed if you give _"appropriate credit"_, provide _"a link to the license"_ and _"indicate if changes were made"_. The latter meaning: use things like `[...]` to indicate you've omitted things, or add a footnote that you've added some formatting to make certain relevant parts stand out more

Comment: I'm not insinuating you had malicious intentions, but having just "thrown the book at you"_, and having just read the CCA3 license: technically, you should include the license, too it seems

Answer (score 0):

The code could be prettier and more realistic, was just trying to be concise. Add thought of apc or xcode cache problem...

Wandering on the interweb for a hint, I read that when calling the same script on two tabs firefox was so intelligent (f... him) that it waited for the first to be done before executing the second.

Adding a different param to each call (?t=1 and ?t=2) or using chrome for one call and ff for the other make it working flawlessly.... What a waste of time....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through the help centre. Posting "thank you" as a comment or answer is in fact highly discouraged. It's simply not an answer. Instead, you're asked to mark helpful answers by up-voting (clicking the grey arrow on the top left of each answer, above the score), and/or mark the answer that solved the problem as accepted (by clicking the large, hollow V sign next each answer). Accepting an answer will grant you +2 reputation, as an encouragement. After doing this, you should delete this non-answer, too

Comment: Also note that ending a question, or answer with greetings or phrases like _"thanks in advance"_ is discouraged. A good question details what you're trying to accomplish, a minimal code example to reproduce, and explains what steps you've taken to resolve the issue. Nothing more. Signatures are considered to be _"noise"_. Same goes for answers. Please avoid adding things like "Regards", even though it seems like the polite thing to do :-P